# Selecting mask of irregular shape in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, masking

How can I select a mask of irregular shape in an image in Matlab without using the imfreehand but automatically? The background of the image is black and I would like to select the entire image as mask just without the black background (everything without the black background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
threshold=0; % or a different value if needed
mask=image>threshold;
```

given that the background is truly black, i.e. pixels values are 0, the set threshold to zero. Otherwise, select a value that captures the background (there are ways to do that automatically)

Comment: then,what should I do in order to display that mask (white mask on black background)? This way I just isolate the pixels that are not black, right?

Comment: just `imagesc(mask); colormap(gray)`